# How can I access another service's EXTERNAL-IP in kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I have a `vault` service in my kubernetes cluster, the type is `LoadBalancer` and it has an `http` endpoint with ip. I want to add this ip as and env variable for another container.

I've already tried to use `$(VAULT_SERVICE_HOST)` but it gives me a `tcp` endpoint, which I can't use because I need `http` or `https`.

A part of my `deployment` config is now like this, but it doesn't work:

```
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: $(APP_IMAGE)
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: $(APP_NAME)
          env:
            - name: VAULT_TOKEN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: $(APP_NAME)
                  key: vault_token
            - name: VAULT_HOST
              value: $(kubectl get svc vault -n default -o jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[*].ip}{'\n'}")
            - name: VAULT_PORT
              value: $(kubectl get svc vault -n default -o jsonpath="{.spec.ports[*].port}{'\n'}")
```

Is it possible to use the ip which I'm getting after running `kubectl get service` in the `EXTERNAL-IP` field as a value of my config?

Comment: Normally you'd just use the other Service name `vault` as a host name; you shouldn't need the externally-visible IP address for a call originating from within the same cluster.  (HTTP and HTTP-over-TLS both run on top of TCP, and the `$VAULT_PORT` – always 8200? – is a TCP port.)